# what alghorithm to use for 6 input values and binary target value - sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have created test data. It consists of 6 features. If sum value of first three features is bigger than sum of last 3 features in a row, then target is 1, else 0.

Now I am playing with sklearn classifiers and KNeighborsClassifier or DecisionTreeClassifier are producing very low score (around 0.7). I would like to ask which classifier would you use in this case and most importantly, why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple linear problem so use a logistic regession. Your theta vector of the trained model should look like [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1] with a very small positive bias

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. It is true, thank you. May I just ask how do you extract algorithm from regression model? Thank you very much.